# How to decrypt this transposition cipher?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, encryption

My problem is that I am trying to decrypt following cipher text:

```
 AWGNEYDTBSREAHGIDEIEEIHKIWABHPRCROIWSSBHTE
 OCSNASLAIGTTOTYIOBNANNOOCHENEHSADUAIEOSNTH
 TEOOAWUTOVTISNTVIFIHSNADVOGOREAPTBETSIT
 DCSNASAAHOOULITUREICBNOERSNETTNOITTNTSDEOO
 RERNINTOVTINTEFKGITPRCROEEIGREIGREHKFN
 HOCWHPDTOSREGTOUREINDIUATHCHIEOSN
```

I know that it is English language. I know that it was encrypted only once by substitution, monoalphabetic or transposition.

I checked the Index of Coincidence and I received: 0.06833754056978002
I also checked frequency of letter and I received:

```
 T 11.02, E 10.59, O 10.16, I 9.74, N 8.47, S 6.77, A 6.35, R 5.93, H 5.93, G 3.38, D 3.38, C 3.38, U 2.54, B 2.54, W 2.11, V 1.69, P 1.69, K 1.27, F 1.27, Y 0.84, L 0.84.
```

So I claim that it is transposition cipher. Am I right?
I checked all combinations of Rail Fence Transposition. I did not receive something sensible.
I checked all combinations of Columnar Transposition without changing order. I did not receive something sensible.
I checked a few combinations of Columnar Transposition with changing order. I did not receive something sensible.

Do you have idea how I can resolve this interesting task?